# When creating a new nav-based iphone app, how do you add a button to the nav bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

When creating a new nav-based iphone app, how do you add a button to the nav bar?

I've tried editing the rootviewcontroller.xib and adding a nav bar and nav item and bar button item, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Is there a simple way of achieving this through IB, or do i have to duck into code somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this requires a little bit of code. Create your `UIBarButtonItem` in interface builder and hook it up to an `IBOutlet` in your view controller. Then, in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Assuming "myButton" is the UIBarButtonItem.
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = myButton;
}
```

Assigning to `rightBarButtonItem` works similarly. See the [UINavigationItem Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html) for more information.

Comment: OK that was the way i was doing it, i just thought there might be an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```